# Howto enqueue all files listed in a file to a vlc playlist using cat and awk

Tags: bash, awk, vlc, playlist, cat

I'm trying to enqueue all files listed in a textfile to a VLC playlist. Every line holds an absolute path to a movie file.

Adding just one file to the playlist works perfectly:

```
vlc --playlist-enqueue someMediaFile
```

I'm also able to execute a command (e.g. print) for every line listed in the textfile using cat and awk like this:

```
cat avis.txt | awk '{print $0}'
```

...

But combined, it doesn't work:

```
cat avis.txt | awk '{vlc --playlist-enqueue $0}'
```

The line above prints the content of the file avis.txt line by line to the standard output while awk reads the data from there line by line using a pipe. awk will also replace $0 with the 'n' line from the file. So every command, executed by awk, will look like this, i thought:

```
vlc --playlist-enqueue firstLineFromAvis.txt
vlc --playlist-enqueue secondLineFromAvis.txt
...
vlc --playlist-enqueue nLineFromAvis.txt
```

But that's not happening. Could someone tell me what am I doing wrong? Can't I execute a programm with parameters using awk like that?

Thanks for reading.

John

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
cat avis.txt | awk '{print "vlc --playlist-enqueue "$0}' > updatedFile.txt
```

Answer (score 5):

```
xargs -a avis.txt -I {} vlc --playlist-enqueue {}
```

Comment: Thanks! Works good, but stops executing after ~100 files?! Any Ideas?

Comment: Hihi, got it! A single quotation mark was causing this problem. Many thanks again!