# Enqueue multiple playlist items from file in vlc using a batch file

Tags: php, batch-file, cmd, vlc, playlist

We have the following scenario:

We want to stream (24h) videos from (VideoLan) VLC to Tablets, Android, BB and other devices. The items for the next day of the playlist of VLC schould be enqueued once or twice a day though a .conf file which just contains the paths to the files like:

```
  "C:\Users\Max\Videos\dog.mp4"
  "http://www.myserver.tv/mobile/video/cat.mp4"
  ...
```

Now I want to read all lines from this file and add them to the playlist of the streaming server. I can add single files to the playlist of one instance of VLC using the following comando:

```
  vlc --started-from-file --playlist-enqueue "C:\Users\Max\Videos\dog.mp4"
```

I wrote a small batch file:

```
@echo off 
cls 
setlocal
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%i IN (playlist.conf) DO vlc --started-from-file --playlist-enqueue --no-playlist-autostart %%i ^ 
     :sout=#transcode{soverlay,ab=64,samplerate=44100,channels=2,acodec=mp4a,vcodec=h264,width=480,height=320,fps=25,vb=400,venc=x264{vbv-bufsize=10000, partitions=all,level=12,no-cabac,subme=7, threads=4, ref=2,mixed-refs=1,bframes=0,min-keyint=1,keyint=50,trellis=2, direct=auto, qcomp=0.0,qpmax=51}}:gather:rtp{mp4a-latm,sdp=rtsp://192.168.1.228:1234/stream.sdp}
```

Now my problem is that the batch file does not simply execute all lines and enqueue them but wait for the video to finish and wait until I close the VLC-Player until it reproduces the next video. 
Basically it is like [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12151318/howto-enqueue-all-files-listed-in-a-file-to-a-vlc-playlist-using-cat-and-awk) another user wanted to resolve on a Linux-Server. The documantacion for VLC Comand Line comandos can be found [here](https://wiki.videolan.org/VLC_command-line_help) => Search for --playlist-enqueue

I was wondering it it is a question of --one-instance-when-started-from-file but as this option is enabled as default I think it is something else is missing.

I also changed my batch file to just start VLC and execute the single comandos like I did from comand line above but it does not work! It still starts playing the first video and waits until it is finished and the instance of VLC closed until it opens up a new instance and plays the next video from the config file.

If you have completely other ideas I also apreciate them.

---

12.09.13 - 11:28:
Ok, it seems that it is a question of how synchronous and asynchronous calling.
I have found s small code part in php from [here](http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.system.php#42567) to call a script which should add my videos to the playlist apparently asynchronous:

```
 for ($i=0; $i<count($convert); $i++){
      system('php -f "C:\xampp\htdocs\playlist\playlist_2.php" args '.urlencode($convert[$i]).'"');
 }
```

"convert" is an array that holds the names from my playlist file above.

1. Php calls the other file (playlist_2.php)
2. VLC opens up BUT
3. the originally calling php file (playlist.php) still waits for VLC to close until it continues the loop and calls playlist_2.php and opens up another instance of VLC. (unwanted behaviour)

So I have the same effect as before. Any ideas?

Comment: why do you use `--no-playlist-autostart` if you need to start immediately?

Comment: I forgot to mention that I already tried that as well.
The `--no-playlist-autostart` just causes that the VLC opens up and waits until you play the file and after finishing and closing VLC it opens up a new instance and reproduces the next video. So that does not help.

Answer (score 0):

I use a command like this to transcode and close VLC

```
start "" /w /min "c:\Program Files\videolan\vlc\vlc.exe" "%%~nxa" --sout #transcode{acodec=mp3,ab=192,channels=2}:std{access=file,mux=raw,dst=temp~.mp3} vlc://quit
```

You may like to try adding this to the end of your command line.

```
vlc://quit
```

Comment: But doesn't this open-close vlc multiple times while adding files?
Perfect would be:
`Open VLC or find the open instance of VLC - Enqueue 1..n files from another file - Done` 
without quiting or anything assuming our stream is running 24/7

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work right now! After several tries.
VLC is very boring with spaces and quotations!

Usually our file names have space, my approach is to use file:/// and transform all spaces in %20 before.

My list was also an array joined by \n as find app gives us ... ;)

```
 m=`find /my/music/dir/ -iname *$1*.mp3`
 m=`echo "$m" | sed -r 's/\ /%20/g'`
 m=`echo "$m" | tr '\n' '~'`
 m=${m::-1} #takes last one \n off, because in my case it existed
 m=`echo "$m" | sed -r 's/\~/ file:\/\/\//g'`
 m="file:///$m"
 vlc $m &
 disown
```

And voilà